# Sobreescribir ficheros con find -mmin y cambio de día

Tags: bash, búsquedas

Tengo montada en mi máquina (Ubuntu Server 16.04) una carpeta remota con sshfs

/home/.../datos/origen

Y tengo un script que toma los ficheros actualizados en los últimos 5 minutos y los copia sobre una carpeta en local. En ocasiones, en la carpeta de origen se publica una nueva versión del fichero con el mismo nombre, machacando la versión anterior, pero en la de destino no se sobreescribe.

Me ocurre precisamente con ficheros entre las 23:55 y las 00:00 por lo que sospecho podría ser algo relacionado con el -mmin.

```
find /home/.../datos/origen -name "*.*" -mmin -15 -exec /bin/cp -rfp "{}" /home/.../datos/destino \;
```

Me pregunto qué estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: No me queda demasiado claro el problema: _a veces se machaca, pero quiero que se sobreescriba_. ¿No son ambas cosas sinónimas?

Comment: Gracias por responder. Ciertamente, no quedaba claro y lo he editado:
En ocasiones, en la carpeta de origen se publica una nueva versión del fichero con el mismo nombre, machacando la versión anterior, pero en la de destino no se sobreescribe.

Comment: Uhms, puestos a mirar cómo sincronizar directorios, ¿por qué no usas directamente [`rsync`](https://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/)?

Comment: Fue una alternativa que se barajó al principio, pero los ficheros que son procesados [esto lo hace un software compilado y opaco] deben ser borrados de la carpeta /home/.../destino para no volver a procesarlos más adelante.
Por otro lado, probamos también con inotifywait, pero este comando lo que hace es capturar los mensajes que se envían al kernel, y como la carpeta de origen es remota, obviamente no sincronizaba.

Comment: Ajá, entiendo, por lo que además de este `find ... cp` entiendo que hacéis un `rm` en algún momento. Por tanto, ciñámonos a la forma actual que tenéis de resolverlo :) A ver, el comando es simple y debe funcionar: `-mmin -15` busca ficheros que se han modificado hace menos de 15 minutos. Se me ocurre que hagas un poco de debugging imprimiendo el listado: `find ... -printf "%p %t\n"` para ver los datos del fichero y si realmente tienen menos de 15 minutos de antigüedad. [Más info sobre `printf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215236/40596).

Comment: Es lo que haremos. Esta noche a las 23:55 veremos lo que pasa, y posiblemente el lunes tendremos alguna respuesta.
El caso es que esto sólo ocurre entre las 23:55 y las 00:00, lo cual no tiene demasiado sentido.

Comment: Idea tal vez tonta: ¿y no podría ser que los ficheros fueran copiados de un servidor que está en una hora diferente y, por tanto, cuando entran consten como 23:00 en lugar de 00:00? No sé si este dato se preserva cuando copias de un fichero a otro.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y no es así y tampoco tiene sentido, pues fallaría en todo momento, no solo en el cambio de día. De todos modos, sería interesante ver más datos. ¿Quién y cómo pone los ficheros en el directorio?

Comment: Los pone un usuario en el sftp, utilizando para ello un software de sincronización con otras máquinas (SYNCAPP), el copiado del sftp montado en nuestra máquina por sshfs lo hace un script

Comment: Sí, hace un rato hemos estado haciendo pruebas y descubierto que la máquina de origen no estaba en hora y que respetaba el timestamp a la hora de sincronizar, siendo esa la causa raíz.
Ah, y quitar las " de "{}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema estaba en la hora de las máquinas origen de datos.

Aparte, eliminamos las comillas dobles del `find`:

```
find /origen -name "*.*" -mmin -15 -exec /bin/cp -rfp {} /destino \;
#                                                     ^^
```

En lugar de:

```
find /origen -name "*.*" -mmin -15 -exec /bin/cp -rfp "{}" /destino \;
#                                                     ^^^^
```

Todo va como la seda tras arreglarlo.